# Trouble centering images in a container and validating result in html 5

Tags: html

I get the following error message when trying to validate in html 5:

Error: The align attribute on the img element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
From line 22, column 21; to line 22, column 114
="divtwo">

The image is on the front of a card and it disappears when I try to center it in css.  Is the best approach to use inline css with align-content: center or to position the image on stylesheet.  Another way?

Also do I need to or can I give the image an id?  I have tried to call the image in cdd with #menuwhite.png or #menuwhite.  Just looking to get pointed in general direction as I am going the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all... You should read the guides on how to ask questions at SO qnd brush up your CSS skills in general...

Long story short:
Align attributes in HTML elements is outdated and not valid in HTML5 anymore.
Thus give the image a class like "card-img" or something and then align and still it in CSS with .card-img{}

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will try the solution you suggested.  I will try to ask questions more clearly in the future.

Comment: Thank you once again.  I altered the html and css as follows.  Your suggestion worked well.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.                                                                                              <div class="divtwo"><img class="menu" src="menuwhite.png" alt="menu"></div>                                                                            .menu {width: 30%; align-content: center; padding-top: 30%; }